# C# LINQ code not working for XML parse

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to use LINQ to parse data from an XML file, but the code I have does not seem to work and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Shortened version of the xml:

```
<Components>
   ....

<Component Id="b3d06054-6113-4775-9353-f48aa21295e8" ProductId="ERDDMR">
  <Sections>
    <ComponentSection Id="bb05507e-200d-494a-9aef-3181c039efc7" ProductSectionId="ERDDMR.Process" />
    <ComponentSection Id="391aead4-cfeb-4739-b8ec-c6b12664189f" ProductSectionId="ERDDMR.Exhaust" />
  </Sections>
  <VariantData Type="eContact">
    <Row Name="dampersize" Value="5610" Description="Return Damper Size" />
    <Row Name="damperactuators" Value="1" Description="Return (0=None, 1=2-Pos, 2=MOD)" />
    <Row Name="damperconstruction" Value="1" Description="Return (0=N/A, 1=VCD-23, 2=VCD-34" />
  </VariantData>
</Component>
<Component Id="f4130a92-aac1-4039-a4df-83d6994ae095" ProductId="ERDSIC">
  <Sections>
    <ComponentSection Id="1e65f0c4-db4f-4eb7-8605-e37f9d7e6f68" ProductSectionId="ERDSIC.1" />
  </Sections>
  <VariantData Type="eContact">
    <!-- *** Find this one, below! *** -->
    <Row Name="dampersize" Value="5926" Description="MUA Damper Size" /> 
    <Row Name="damperactuators" Value="1" Description="MUA (0=None, 1=2-Pos, 2=MOD)" />
    <Row Name="damperconstruction" Value="1" Description="MUA (0=N/A, 1=VCD-23, 2=VCD-34, 3=VCD-40" />
  </VariantData>
</Component>

...
</Components>
```

I'm trying to find the attribute **Value** of the Row Element that has attribute Name = "dampersize" and is a descendant of the Element "Component" whose attribute ProductId = "ERDSIC"  (I identified it in the xml above)

My failed attempt is here:

```
var prop = xDoc.Elements("Component")
              .Where(c => c.Attribute("ProductId").Value == "ERDSIC")
                 .Descendants("Row").Where(t => t.Attribute("Name").Value == "dampersize")
                    .Select(v => v.Attribute("Value").Value).FirstOrDefault();

 Console.WriteLine("Result: " + prop.ToString());
```

The error I get is (located on the Console.WriteLine line):

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

**EDIT** - Changed "Type" to "Name"  the code is still wrong

Comment: Shouldnt `..Attribute("Type")` be `..Attribute("Name")`?

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed and edited it and its still giving me the same error.

Comment: Could you post stack trace in order to clarify somehow whats going on

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you should find eContact in linq first, and then   .Descendants("Row").Where(t => t.Attribute("Name").Value == "dampersize")
                    .Select(v => v.Attribute("Value").Value).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Well I am not familiar with linq over xml. Is `Descendants("Row")` really stepping over `VariantData`? At that point you are in the context of the component.

Comment: @juharr He's not selecting the value of the component in his `Where`. He's accessing the value of the attribute `ProductId` isn't he? I really thing the problem is he's not selecting `VariantData` in here.

Comment: I'd suggest breaking down the query into each part to see the intermediate results and debugging to find the problem.

Comment: if `xDoc` is `XDocument` then use `xDoc.Root.`. If `xDoc` is `XElement` then it will work.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Is right.  If you load that into an `XDocuemnt` and use `xDoc.Root` with your code the result is 5926.

Comment: I ran the OP's code and it worked fine. It appears to me that his problem is that his XML is not being loaded into `prop` and is therefore `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you cast to get value instead of use the `Value` property to avoid this kind of error, I think there is a node that doesn't have the attribute or you misspelled some name,

```
var prop = xDoc.Root.Elements("Component")
              .Where(c => (string)c.Attribute("ProductId") == "ERDSIC")
                 .Descendants("Row").Where(t => (string)t.Attribute("Name") == "dampersize")
                    .Select(v => (string)v.Attribute("Value")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: please downvoter, could you explain why to improve my answer, thanks in advance

Comment: This is not the problem.  The issue is that you need to query off `xDoc.Root`.  Basically the `Elements` part is returning an empty collection and that results in a `null` from the `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: They still need to use `Elements` because there is more than one with that name.  Otherwise you cannot do a `Where` on a single element.

Comment: Hi @juharr, yes I noticed that in your comments as well as Alexander comments and I fixed that. Thanks for the feedbacks

Comment: Note that simply adding the `Root` fixes the issue.  While casting versus using `Value` is a good idea it's not the "root" of the problem (sorry for the pun).

Comment: @juharr, no worries, I thought at the beginning was for some misspelling of some of the names, it wasn't clear how the user load the xml

Answer (score 3):

If `xDoc` is `XDocument` type:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
```

then use the `Root` property:

```
var prop = xDoc.Root.Elements("Component")
```

Or change the `xDoc` type to `XElement`:

```
var xDoc = XElement.Load("test.xml");
```

Then your code will be fully working.

Comment: I actually use:   `XElement xDoc = XElement.Parse(xml)`  because my xml is in the form of a string. I noticed `Load` is looking specifically for a file. Is there a way to use XElement to load an xml string?

Comment: @bagofmilk Using `Load` or `Parse` does not matter. Did you show the real xml? Do you have any namespace in the xml?

Answer (score 0):

If I put the OP's XML in a file called `Data.xml` in the `\bin\Debug` folder and run the following, it works, so I can only assume that his method for loading the XML is not working and `prop` is null.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Work
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] _)
        {
            var folder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            var path = Path.Combine(folder, "Data.xml");
            var xml = XElement.Load(path);

            var prop = xml.Elements("Component")
                .Where(c => c.Attribute("ProductId").Value == "ERDSIC")
                .Descendants("Row").Where(t => t.Attribute("Name").Value == "dampersize")
                .Select(v => v.Attribute("Value").Value).FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + prop);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is almost definitely loading it as a `XDocument` instead of a `XElement`.